# Vacuum to vacuum transition amplitude confusion

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum, path-integral

Quantum field theory texts often use the expression $\langle 0,\infty|0,-\infty\rangle_J\,$ denoting the vacuum-to-vacuum transition amplitude.

1. What is the meaning of $|0,-\infty\rangle_J?$ Am I to take the Hamiltonian with the source present, ie. $H(t)=H-J(t)q(t)\,,$ find the ground state at time $0\,,$ ie. $H(0)=E_0|0\rangle$ and evolve it backwards to $-\infty?$
2. Why isn't the correct expression $_J\langle 0,\infty|0,-\infty\rangle_J$ instead? I also see $\langle q',t'|q,t\rangle_J$ and have the same question about that, ie. what is $|q,t\rangle_J$ and why aren't we considering $_J\langle q',t'|q,t\rangle_J$ instead?

[Reference](https://books.google.ca/books?id=A9MU9pvcEGQC&pg=PA8&lpg=PA8&dq=ground+state+in+presence+of+a+source&source=bl&ots=MceDcVL9tG&sig=YfZ6lY4uStodu4GNbc7nLGFpRLs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMIqIDRiI_bxgIViaweCh0CUA7I#v=onepage&q=ground%20state%20in%20presence%20of%20a%20source&f=false)

Comment: I believe this is sloppy notation. It is not the dot product of $|0,-\infty\rangle_J$ and $|0,\infty\rangle$. Rather, it is a modification of the standard partition function $\langle 0,\infty|0,-\infty\rangle$ by a term involving $J$. Thus, for example, $(\langle 0,\infty|0,-\infty\rangle)_J$ would be better.

Comment: @0celo7 What about here? They say $|0,t\rangle^J$ is the vacuum in the presence of a source: https://books.google.ca/books?id=FC_DRRUHFXEC&pg=PA129&lpg=PA129&dq=vacuum+to+vacuum+transition+amplitude+in+the+presence+of+a+source&source=bl&ots=Pj8sTtft_1&sig=Dq5SUSPOodVvzaEvlqGK5rc5ytQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDAQ6AEwBGoVChMIjJLxmY7bxgIVg20eCh17bwTG#v=onepage&q=vacuum%20to%20vacuum%20transition%20amplitude%20in%20the%20presence%20of%20a%20source&f=false

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but they might just be lazy and are writing $^J\langle 0,\infty |0,-\infty\rangle ^J$ and omitting the left $J$.

Comment: @0celo7 I thought about that, but in the first link I posted, inside the integral they put precisely one J and it seems to be on purpose.

Comment: The first link is a standard treatment. Giving a special meaning to $|0,t\rangle^J$ is not standard. (Zee, Weinberg, Srednicki and Peskin & Schroeder do not give it special meaning, for what it's worth.)

Comment: @0celo7 Hm but Ryder does.

Comment: Well, what does he say about it?

Comment: @0celo7 It's the vacuum (in the moving frame) in the presence of a source.

Comment: That's a lazy way of putting it. What is the *mathematical definition*?

Comment: @0celo7 I basically just quoted him. He doesn't really say anything else.

Comment: You should join the h Bar chat so we can discuss this. Basically, since those authors don't really give it meaning and other authors don't even mention it, you can gloss over this.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a good question and need to be addressed because this is very often not explained well in books.

The notation $|0,\pm\rangle_j$ has no meaning. But the expression, $(\langle 0,+\infty|0,-\infty\rangle)_j\equiv \langle 0,+\infty|0,-\infty\rangle_j$ is perfectly meaningful. Let me explain what does it represent.

Consider a system being subjected to an externally applied time-dependent "perturbation" $j(t)$. We look for the effect of this
perturbation on the transition amplitude $\langle q_f,t_f|q_i,t_i\rangle$. I put the word perturbation in quotations. Because at the moment,
it's an arbitrary function of time, and I don’t assume it to be small. Sometimes $j(t)$ is called a source term  which can be thought of as a external field like an electric field $\textbf{E}(t)$. To ensure that $j(t)$ enters the equation of motion as an inhomogeneous source, a term $q(t)j(t)$ has to be added to the Lagrangian so that:
$$L\to L + q(t)j(t).$$ For concreteness, assume that the system is a linear harmonic oscillator. Suppose that I prepare the system in the
ground state at $t=-\infty$. I’ll call denote it by $|0_-\rangle\equiv |0,-\infty\rangle$. At some finite past $t =-\tau$, I turn on a time-dependent "perturbation" $j(t)$, let it act for sometime, and then switch it off at time $t\to +\tau$. Then let the system evolve asymptotically to $t\to +\infty$ on its own. Whatever state the system evolves to will be
denoted by $|0_+\rangle\equiv |0,+\infty\rangle$. If you wish, you can call it the ground state at $t=+\infty$.

Now here is the word of caution. The state $|0_+\rangle$ need not be same as $|0_-\rangle$. At $t=+\infty$, the system has a finite probability to be found in any of the excited states. Therefore, the overlap $\langle 0_+|0_-\rangle_j\leq 1$ in presence of $j$. If $j$ never acted
this overlap would have been equal to $1$.

Comment: How negative time; i.e., $t \to - \infty$ is possible? In other words, what does it physically mean when time $t \to - \infty$?

Comment: $t\to -\infty$ means "times much earlier than when the perturbation is turned on and $t\to +\infty$ means "times much later than when the perturbation is turned off. In my answer, the perturbation acted during a finite interval $-\tau\leq t\leq +\tau$ about $t=0$. @rainman