# Derivation operators as arguments or the Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, partition-function, functional-derivatives

In a book I am reading about QFT (*Quantum field theory* by Mark Srednicki ,page 48), I see the following equation:
$$
\int \mathcal D p\mathcal D q \exp\left[i\int_{\mathbb R} dt (p\dot q - H_0(p,q)-H_1(p,q) +fq+hp)\right] $$
$$=\exp\left[i\int_{\mathbb R} dt (H_1(i\delta/\delta h(t),i\delta/\delta f(t)))\right]$$
$$\times \int \mathcal D p\mathcal D q \exp\left[i\int_{\mathbb R} dt (p\dot q - H_0(p,q)+fq+hp)\right] \tag{6.22}
$$
where

- $H=H_0+H_1$ is the Hamiltonian of the system, and $H_1$ is a small perturbation.
- $\mathcal D q$ denotes path integral.
- $\delta/\delta f(t)$ is the functional derivative operator; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative#Functional_derivative_of_a_function) for the definition.

I do not understand how this equation works. Why could we insert differential operators in the place of $p,q$.  And if I take the part $\exp\left[i\int_{\mathbb R} dt (H_1(i\delta/\delta h(t),i\delta/\delta f(t)))\right]$ under the integral sign, I find that it the operator has nothing to act on.

**How to understand this equation?**

Comment: *the operator has nothing to act on* That’s not true. It has the integral to its right, which contains $h(t)$ and $f(t)$, to act on.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Srednicki's Path Integrals: Ground-State to Ground-State Transition Amplitude in the Presence of a Perturbation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/268368/2451)

Comment: This operator differentiates the integral with $H_0$ with respect to $f$ and $h$

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at an ordinary integral
\begin{equation}
\mathcal Z(h) = \int dx e^{-f(x) + xh},
\end{equation}
with $f(x)$ such that the integral is convergent. It should be obvious that
\begin{equation}
\int dx \, x \, e^{-f(x)+xh} = \frac{\partial}{\partial h} \int dx \, e^{-f(x)+xh}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
\int dx \, x^n \, e^{-f(x)+xh} = \frac{\partial^n}{\partial h^n} \int dx \, e^{-f(x)+xh}.
\end{equation}
Now using those you can easily get
\begin{eqnarray}
I(h) & = & \int dx \, g(x) \, e^{-f(x)+xh} = \int dx \, \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{g^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n \, e^{-f(x)+xh}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{g^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\int dx \, x^n \, e^{-f(x)+xh} \\
& = &
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{g^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\frac{\partial^n}{\partial h^n}\int dx \, e^{-f(x)+xh}=g\left (\frac{\partial}{\partial h} \right) \int dx \, e^{-f(x)+xh}
\end{eqnarray}
In your specific case $g(x)$ is an exponent